# Can we compile a Tensorflow Model?

Tags: tensorflow

Let me be more clear giving our use case: We developed a service that makes predictions using Tensorflow. One of our clients would like to use it locally (in his on-premise servers), and we don't want because it's like giving him the model that he can replicate and train (we are billing improvements/maintenance).

If there is a way to make our TF model compiled, he would not be able to find the model graph and parameters. Is there a way to compile a Tensorflow model in an irreversible way?

If not, is there another way to protect our model?

Comment: Could you maybe just make a REST API for your client and store the model on the server?

Comment: That's our original offering, but the client requires on premise use of the model because the ingested data is "sensitive" and he cannot send it to the cloud (or any external resource).

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't be worried for a client to "hack" the model and extract some data from it. Even for a regular programmer that's hard to do, let alone the clients. Also, you'll always have a better/next version of the model (if you continue to train it), so if the client decides to run away with your work you have a leverage. So I guess it's both unlikely and not threatening. But to answer your original question — no, I don't think it's possible to use the model and "hide" it at the same time.